# How can combining two ethereal substances that naturally repel amplify each others effects?

Tags: science-fiction, religion

Angels and demons come from the ethereal realm, a plane of pure energy. The former is made up of pure ether while the latter is made up of a corrupted version. These forces naturally repel each other, like two magnets being pushed together or mixing oil and water. For this reason, it is impossible for angels and demons to interbreed.

However, a solution exists in the form of humanity. A human soul is a tabula rasa of sorts, a blank slate that is free of angelic or demonic energy. Using the soul as a base allows both energies to exist in equilibrium, balancing each other out. This allows both forms to combine properly and amplify each other's effects, making the resulting individual potentially stronger than their parent races. Through an immaculate conception, a human was born on earth with this duality, who is being poached by both sides to join them and their interests.

Why would combining two substances that wouldn't mix in nature amplify each other?

Comment: Oil plus water won't get you far. Oil (or fat) plus (flavoured, acidic) water plus egg yolk gives you mayonnaise or hollandaise and all the rest, which is obviously amazing and superior to the components individually. Also emergent properties can't be reasonably established ahead of time by looking at the substrate they arose from, so the answer could just be "because of blind luck and coincidence". Also, it is lunchtime, hence food analogies.

Comment: Solving those unsolvable contradictions is what gives you the most interesting engine that can run all your book. I am not sure it is clever to use somebodies' solutions for THAT.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, so what you're suggesting is that we take samples of angels and demons, grind them down, mix them with egg yolk and put it on our fries?

Comment: Holy sperms: just keep swimming... Demon egg: thou shall not pass. Holy sperm king: observe I shall tunnel through this energy barrier, hold my beer...

Comment: Happens all the time in nature. I like L Dutch's electricity analogy, bar magnets come to mind straight away for me as well. Demon = negative charge, Angel = positive charge, and metal alloy = human.

Answer (score 5):

Both substances, taken together, cover a wider spectrum of applications, barren to the individual components.

Let's make a similitude with electric charge. Take a proton or an electron alone. It makes it's nice electric field, which you can hardly use except than for interacting with other charges.

Put an electron and a proton together (they don't repel each other, but they have opposite charge), you get:

- a dipole, which you can use to generate EM waves and communicate if you induce an oscillation in it
- a neutral atom, which has other fancy ways of interacting with the surrounding environment

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself: like water and oil.

Some substances only dissolve in polar solvents (i.e.: water). Some only dissolve in apolar solvents (i.e.: oil). If you have an apolar thing inside a tank of water and you want to get it out, in the absence of soap... You can add oil to the top, provoke a whirlpool, and the oil will temporarily mix in with the water and dissolve stuff. Then, when both liquids settle, oil is back on top and you can scoop whatever it is you wanted.

Think of it like this: angelic mana knows how to heal, but due to its nature, it will only heal "good" creatures. Negative plane ones are actually harmed by healing spells. Your special human, though, can use the healing aspect with the demonic energy, and this is able to heal corrupted creatures (a very unique skill!)

On the other hand, demonic energy can be used to mind control people, but angelic beings are immune becaude their mana vibes differently. No problem! The special human uses the same technique, but with angelic mana instead... And now he can mind control angels.

Your character may also do things such as being able to cast both *smite good* and *smite evil*, so neither side has got nothing on him. You would expect everyone else to be able to cast only one or another.

Answer (score 1):

If two repelling components are built into us, than that pair is as source of energy, and  more repelling they are, more energy a person has.

Another question is how to combine them. Obviously, these two components are almost zero at start and they and their strength grows during life or after some deeds.

How can we hold them together? Let us say, by strength of our will/character.

Comment: much like taping butter side up toast on the back of a cat. The butter always lands face down but cats always land on their feet. Viola! infinite energy. The infinitely swirling mass of dark and light energies amplifies their potential.

Comment: @ITAlex Yess! That sorcery pseudo-logic can prove absolutely everything and provide any engine. We should only check it to be nice and beautiful.